# Why does including an orderBy statement not return all records?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When querying firestore, if I include an orderBy it will limit to 10 records. Removing the orderBy will return all 100 records.

I've tried ordering by different fields, such as id, but regardless the results will be limited. I also created appropriate composite indexes as necessary.

The following will return 10 rows:

```
db.collection('transactions').where('uid', '==', 'myuserid').orderBy('transaction.date', 'desc').orderBy('id', 'asc').limit(100).get()
```

Without the orderBy, the expected 100 rows are returned. But of course, the results are unordered:

```
db.collection('transactions').where('uid', '==', 'myuserid').limit(100).get()
```

EDIT: Also found that doing 1 orderBy seems to work ok too:

```
db.collection('transactions').where('uid', '==', 'myuserid').orderBy('transaction.date', 'desc').limit(100).get()
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the index and the data not being adjacent to each other. But without any visibility into the indexes there's no way to know. 10 results (consistently) is very odd though.

Comment: Do the documents that are not returned have the `transaction.date` field? Only documents that contain a field are going to be in the index on that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but `orderBy` on a requested field would also do the filtering by default based on existence of the provided field. The returned resultset excludes records that do not have the requested field.

Refer : [Google Firestore order/limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)

Comment: True, but all documents should have an id field, so this still doesn't explain why adding the orderBy('id') would limit the results.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the comments, they led me to the solution -- there happened to be 10 documents that had an 'id' key in them and so that's why only those showed up. I mistakenly thought that by ordering by 'id', it would order by the id of the document.